# Classification of derived formal group laws

Tags: homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory, higher-algebra, formal-groups

Denote by $SCR$ the $\infty$-category of "simplicial commutative rings" (i.e. the nonabelian derived category of the category of finitely generated polynomial rings). Given $R \in SCR$, one can make sense of $Spf(R[[t]]): SCR \to Spc$, namely this is the subfunctor of the functor corepresented by the formal power series ring $R[[t]] \in SCR$ consisting of those homomorphisms which are continuous on $\pi_0$ (i.e. annihilate some power of $t$).
By a formal group law on $R$ I mean a lift of the functor $Spf(R[[t]])$ to connective $H\mathbb{Z}$-modules.

Unless I made some mistake, all of these definitions should be straightforward adaptations of section 2 in Lurie's second paper on elliptic cohomology to simplicial commutative rings.

**Here is my actual question:** Denote the space of formal group laws on $R \in SCR$ by $F(R)$. I think that by formal nonsense, the functor $F$ is corepresented by some $\mathbb{L} \in SCR$. Do we know $\pi_i \mathbb{L}$ for $i > 0$?

Wishful thinking leads me to ask if those higher groups might all vanish?

**Remark 1**: Again by formal nonsense $\pi_0 \mathbb{L}$ corepresents the functor of formal group laws on ordinary commutative rings; i.e. this is the Lazard ring.

**Remark 2**: We can ask the same question with (connective) $\mathcal E_\infty$-rings in place of simplicial commutative rings. In this case the higher homotopy groups cannot possibly be zero, but I still wonder what they are.

Comment: I'm sure it does not answer your questions, but you should look at the paper by Schwede if you haven't already: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0402372